# Is "builtInEntity" a new requirement for Build-in Entities?

Tags: jhipster

With the 8 release, the JDL import command yields something like

```
 ERROR! In the relationship between MyEntity and User, MyEntity and User are not declared. If 'User' is a built-in entity declare like 'MyEntity to User with builtInEntity'.
```

Searching "builtInEntity" yields no result on jhipster.tech. If that is a new feature/requirement, it should be properly documented.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this will work but its not documented

```
relationship OneToMany {
    Post{user} to User with builtInEntity
}
```

refer to this related issue. The good Matt Raible confirmed it
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/22844